# Service Systems Problem with Repair

Tags: queueing-theory, poisson-process

Can anyone help me with this problem?

> A data centre is equipped with $M = 5$ servers, completely interchangeable.
>   Each of them can fail independently of the others. The time to failure of a
>   running server is a negative exponential random variable with mean $\frac1v = 7$ days. There is only one technician repairing failed servers. Repair times have
>   negative exponential pdf with mean $\frac{1}{\mu} = 1 $ day.
>
> 1. Calculate the probability that no server is operating (all are down) and
>      the mean number of operational servers.
> 2. Find the minimum value of $M$ that guarantees that the unavailability of
>      the system is $10^{-3}$.
>
> Note: *unavailability* = *probability that all servers are down*).

Comment: Show us your work so far, please.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N$ be the number of working machines. Note that $N$ is a continuous-time Markov chain (a birth--and--death process even). The transition rates are

\begin{align}
q_{i,i + 1} &= (M - i)v, \quad 0 \le i \le M - 1, \\
q_{i,i - 1} &= \mu, \quad 1 \le i \le M.
\end{align}

I assume you are interested in the probabilities in the stationary case. Let us call the equilibrium probabilities $\pi_i$. You are interested in $\pi_M$ and $\mathbb{E}[N]$.

Can you continue from here?